# Screen freezes with surface frame wait timed out error while using SIliCompressor

Tags: java, android, video-processing

I'm using SiliCompressor to compress videos. I added the dependency. But when i try to compress it. I get the Surface Frame Timed Out Warning. And my phone freezes.

```
           try {
            String filePath = SiliCompressor.with(WritePost.this).compressVideo(data.getData(), folder.getAbsolutePath());
                            Log.i("Filepath",filePath);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
```

Log

```
I/MediaCodec: [OMX.qcom.video.decoder.avc] setting surface generation to 25656321
02-01 12:59:41.616 25055-26886/package_name I/ExtendedACodec: setupVideoDecoder()
02-01 12:59:41.616 25055-26886/package_name I/ExtendedACodec: vpp-enable search is 0 and value is 0
02-01 12:59:41.622 25055-26886/package_name I/ExtendedACodec: Decoder will be in frame by frame mode
02-01 12:59:41.655 25055-26886/package_name D/SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0x7fa2ebbe10 for 1920x1080, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x2002900
02-01 12:59:41.719 25055-26886/package_name D/SurfaceUtils: set up nativeWindow 0x7fa2ebbe10 for 1920x1088, color 0x7fa30c06, rotation 0, usage 0x2002900
02-01 12:59:41.759 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: newFormat = {crop-top=0, crop-right=1919, color-format=2141391878, height=1088, color-standard=1, crop-left=0, color-transfer=3, stride=1920, mime=video/raw, slice-height=1088, width=1920, color-range=2, crop-bottom=1079, hdr-static-info=java.nio.HeapByteBuffer[pos=0 lim=25 cap=25]}
02-01 12:59:46.765 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 12:59:48.986 25055-25196/package_name I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Loading module via FirebaseOptions.
02-01 12:59:48.986 25055-25196/package_name I/FirebaseAuth: [FirebaseAuth:] Preparing to create service connection to gms implementation
02-01 12:59:51.772 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 12:59:56.779 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:00:01.785 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:00:06.791 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:00:11.834 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:00:11.967 25055-25061/package_name I/art: Do partial code cache collection, code=229KB, data=208KB
02-01 13:00:11.967 25055-25061/package_name I/art: After code cache collection, code=229KB, data=208KB
02-01 13:00:11.967 25055-25061/package_name I/art: Increasing code cache capacity to 1024KB
02-01 13:00:11.969 25055-25061/package_name I/art: Compiler allocated 9MB to compile boolean com.iceteck.silicompressorr.videocompression.MediaController.convertVideo(java.lang.String, java.io.File, int, int, int)
02-01 13:00:16.846 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:00:21.858 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:00:26.864 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:00:31.945 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:00:36.958 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:00:41.966 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:00:47.028 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:00:52.039 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:00:57.046 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:01:02.107 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:01:07.113 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:01:12.117 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:01:17.123 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:01:22.172 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:01:27.177 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
02-01 13:01:32.183 25055-25055/package_name E/tmessages: Surface frame wait timed out
```

Need Help :(

Comment: are you calling `compressVideo` from the UI thread?

Comment: has anyone solved this?